# Reproduzir nota musical por JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Preciso criar um código que reproduza o som conforme as notas musicais informadas...

```
function music(){
     var partitura = '';
     var escala = 'CDEFGABC';
     var notas = escala.split('');
     for (var i = 0; i < notas.length; i++){
         reproduzir(notas[i]);
     }
}
```

Por enquanto, encontrei esta [biblioteca](https://github.com/eshiota/retro-audio-js), que não consegui entender o suficiente para adaptar ao meu código.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A API que você encontrou faz 99% do trabalho. Se você não for utilizá-la, ou irá utilizar outra API, ou terá que reimplementá-la de qualquer forma.

Para usar suas notas com a API, você faria o seguinte:

```
// importe a biblioteca
let player = new Retro.Player();
let minhaSingelaCancao = JSON.stringify({
    title : "mi-mi-re-do",
    tempo : 60,
    time_signature : "4/4",
    score : [{
        instrument : "oscillator-square",
        volume : 0.5,
        sheet : [ "E.4", "E.4", "D.4", "C.4", "C.4", "D.4", "E.4", "F.4", "G.4", "G.4", "F.4", "E.4", "E.4", "D.4", "D.4" ]
    }]
});

player.load(mysong);
player.play();
```

Alguns comentários: se você quer tocar música desse jeito, você vai ter que aprender um mínimo de notação e teoria musical. Por exemplo, se você não compreender o que são o tempo e o compasso (em inglês, *time signature*), você simplesmente não vai conseguir fazer o que você quer fazer de forma satisfatória.

Note também que seu exemplo de notas não inclui a oitava nem a duração de cada nota - se você não as informar, por padrão a biblioteca vai assumir que todas as notas são semibreves e da quarta oitava. Em outras palavras, seu trecho musical soará estacato dependendo de como a biblioteca for interpretar. Por exemplo, suas notas começam com dois *lás*. Se a intenção era essa, beleza, senão... Infelizmente a biblioteca não suporta notação para breve, mas você pode reduzir o tempo pela metade (ou mudar o compasso) e depois marcar todas as demais notas como mínimas.

Comment: Pra cada arquivo da API, aparece no Console: "Uncaught ReferenceError: Module is not defined". Por que isso ocorre? E a música também não toca...

Comment: @lucaswmolin Se não carregar os arquivos corretamente, é óbvio que não vai tocar... Quanto ao erro, é de inclusão. Você pode abrir uma nova pergunta sobre isso, incluindo seu código HTML, para que a gente possa ajudar.